# Refer 'To' field in Outlook to cell

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a macro on Excel VBA that will create an email and will populate the `To` field from the Excel cell `K6`.

When this code runs, I get the error message `Run-time error'5': Invalid procedure call or argument`.

```
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim MItem As Object
Dim cell As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim Subj As String
Dim EmailAddr As String
Dim myRecipient As Object
Dim myRecipients As Object
Dim Recipient As String
Dim Msg As String
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim DateNow As Date

Set ws1 = Sheets("Email")

'Create Outlook object

Set rng = ws1.Range("B6:F26").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With


Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set MItem = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
Set myRecipients = MItem.Recipients

myRecipients = ws1.Cells.Range("K6")

If Not myRecipients.ResolveAll Then

 For Each myRecipient In myRecipients

 If Not myRecipient.Resolved Then

 MsgBox myRecipient.Name

 End If

 Next

 End If

DateNow = Format(Now, "dd/MM/yyyy")
DateNow2 = Format(Now, "h:mm")

Msg = "This report was generated on " & DateNow & " at " & DateNow2 & "."

With MItem
    .CC = EmailAddr2
    .Subject = Subj
    .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng) & Msg
    .Display
End With
On Error GoTo 0

With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Set MItem = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

If I use `Set myRecipients = ws1.Cells.Range("K6")` I get the error message `Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method`.

If I set the `myRecipients As String`, it says `Object required`.

I'm having lots of problems to understand late-binding Outlook in Excel VBA and I've read lots of things, but haven't found many sources on it that could explain this in a more didactic way.

Besides that, I'm also trying to, after adding the content of the cell, to Resolve (the effect of using ctrl + K on Outlook to resolve the email to the display name) the emails added to the `To` field, but I can't test it without making the first part work.

Thanks for the attention,

Edit: after Bruce Wayne's suggestion, I put them as `Range`, but now I'm getting a different error: `Run-time error '-2147352567 (800200009)': Property is read-only.`

`Dim myRecipient As Range
Dim myRecipients As Range`

In the middle of the code:

```
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set MItem = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

Set myRecipients = ws1.Cells.Range("K6")
Set MItem.Recipients = myRecipients
```

After Dmitry's suggestion:

```
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set MItem = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

Set myRecipients = ws1.Cells.Range("K6")
Set myRecipient = MItem.Recipients.Add(myRecipients)

If Not myRecipients.ResolveAll Then

 For Each myRecipient In myRecipients

 If Not myRecipient.Resolved Then

 MsgBox myRecipient.Name

 End If

 Next

 End If
```

But I get the error message: `Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method` marked on the `If Not myRecipients.ResolveAll Then`. If I delete all the If part, the code runs fine. But it's very important to me that I'm able to resolve the names and emails in the To/CC fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recipients property is indeed read-only. You need to either call MailItem.Recipients.Add for each recipient or set the To / CC/ BCC properties to a ";" separated list of names or addresses.

UPDATE:

```
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set MItem = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
Set recipName = ws1.Cells.Range("K6").Value
Set myRecipient = MItem.Recipients.Add(recipName)
If Not myRecipient.Resolve Then
  MsgBox myRecipient.Name
End If
```

Comment: I'm just having difficulty in doing the `If Not ResolveAll` part. It says that `myRecipients` don't support the property or method. 

But I'm thinking that what I'm doing now isn't making much sense: `If Not myRecipients.ResolveAll Then
 
 For Each myRecipient In myRecipients
 
 If Not myRecipient.Resolved Then
 
 MsgBox myRecipient.Name
 ` while myRecipients is a cell... I'm updating that in the post so you can see it more clearly

Comment: Because myRecipients variable in your code above points to a range from Excel, not to an instance of the Outlook.Recipients object retrieved from MailItem.Recipients

Comment: But how can I make it consider that after retrieving the information from the Excel cell and inserting that in the To field it will test if the recipients are resolved?

Comment: You need to fix the error in your code. See my updated post.

Comment: Nice! It is working very well, but just for one email at a time. If my K6 cell is `name.surname@company.com` it will resolve. If it is `name.surname@company.com; name2.surname2@company.com` it won't resolve. I tried moving the `;` but still no results. 

Since it's .Recipients, I imagined that it would take more than one, right?

Comment: Firstly, it would definitely be better to have multiple cells each containing just one value. That is the whole point of Excel, is it not? If you have multiple ";" separated values, just set the MailItem.To property and call MAilItem.Recipients.ResolveAll

Comment: I understand that. The idea is that in the Emails sheet I have all the information needed to create the email. The To field shouldn't vary too much, but it's easier to edit the list like that. 

I will test here, thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95457/discussion-between-ugo-portela-pereira-and-dmitry-streblechenko).

Answer (score 0):

I think it's due to the fact that you're setting `myRecipients` and `myRecipient` as an Object but want to set it with what is essentially a `Range` type.  Try:

```
Dim myRecipients as Range, myRecipient as Range
Dim objMyRecipients as Object, objMyRecipient as Object 'create a variable that holds the object
```

Then, when you need to use them as an object, you have a separate variable to do so.

Comment: That makes sense, but I made some changes and now I'm receiving the `Run-time error '-2147352567 (800200009)': Property is read-only.` I will add the changes I made to the original post for further clarification.